# Adb returns "device not found" in recovery mode

Tags: android, adb, ubuntu-14.04

I try to access an android device (Samsung Galaxy Y) through usb using adb. When the phone is running as usual, with USB debugging activated, adb works just fine and I see the device with a call to "adb devices". However I need adb access in the recovery mode (I want to execute fsck on /data and thus need to unmount it first). I reboot the phone in recovery mode and run CWM (ClockworkMod ROM Manager) but then the phone does not show up with "adb devices".

I looked this up and it appears that on windows systems the solution is to change the drivers. However I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I am stuck with my problem. I tried several suggestions of udev rules in /etc/udev/rules.d but none worked for me.

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I've found that running `adb kill-server`, followed by `su -c adb {command}` works pretty well in these situations.  It's a tiny bit ugly, but some devices refuse to recognize adb unless it's started by root.

Note that you probably can't use `sudo adb {command}` unless your root user has the android tools on its path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but the phone still doesn't show up on the device list.

Answer (score 0):

Possible, try "fastboot devices". It might work in recovery mode. There is a good explanation of adb/fastboot usages here: 
http://lifehacker.com/the-most-useful-things-you-can-do-with-adb-and-fastboot-1590337225

Comment: You could make this a better answer if you included a link to source for your information

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but "fastboot devices" still doesn't list my phone in recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

In my case using another TWRP gave me ADB sideload access.

Answer (score -2):

When you get to the phone into recovery mode unplug the USB plug and then plug it back in again. Windows should search for the driver. When windows finishes open device manager. Look for the nexus 6 with the yellow icon. Follow the steps attached in the picture.

[image]

[image]

> Credit goes to `Intub8` and for the driver steps to `wugfresh`, steps obtained from his toolkit.

Comment: A simple explanation would be really helpful as just downvoting is just kind of confusing.

Comment: My best guess: OP stated that they were using Ubuntu, not Windows.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I overlooked it.